# which one is more appropriate among the two mentioned below?

Tags: irregular-plurals

Roles of private defence firms in developing a domestic military-industrial complex

or

Role of private defence firms in developing a domestic military-industrial complex

Comment: Do they have a single role or multiple roles?

Comment: It depends on what you're going to discuss.